# Local Variables in EJS

Tags: nodes, ejs

but am quite confused of the following code from the lecture.

```
value="<%= (!!locals.email)?email:'' %>"
```

Can anyone explain to me what what this is?

Answer (score 1):

This is a conditional statement using the ternary operator which will select email (1st option) on true or empty string ('') if false.

The local variable `locals.email` is same as `!!locals.email`

`!` is a negation operator(Logical NOT) and if there is no value in email or if its null or undefined or empty string it should return false. So, here we are adding using two negation which becomes positive.

Hence,
`locals.email` is same as `!!locals.email`

Answer (score 0):

!! Converts Object to boolean. If it was falsey (e.g. 0, null, undefined, etc.), it will be false, otherwise, true.

```
!oObject  // inverted boolean
!!oObject // non inverted boolean so true boolean representation
```

So in your case, if locals.email is not falsey then it will take value of email else value=''.

Comment: Thanks! My other questions here are: 1, What exactly does "local variable" mean here? 2, What does that "?" do after the boolean?